# SQL query performance issues on SQL Server 2022 with ADO (compared to MS Access)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, ms-access, performance-testing

I have the same table with the same data on 2 databases (**SQL Server Express 2022** and **MS Access 2016** with a .MDB 2002-2003), containing about 100,000 records. Both tables are indexed (index is named ID).

I connect to them using **ADO**. Connection type for SQL Server is "**shared memory**" (the fastest method) since scripts and databases reside on the same machine.
Databases were installed by using the *default configuration*, I didn't tweak any parameter.
Here are the connection strings I'm using:

**MSACCESS:** PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=xxxxx

**SQL SERVER:** Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;DataTypeCompatibility=80;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=yyyyy;Password=zzzzz;Use Encryption for Data=False;Persist Security Info=True;TrustServerCertificate=True

For benchmarking, I'm using this simple query:

*SELECT value FROM [fad] WHERE userid=[random] AND module=1 AND course=1*

After running this query for 2,000 times, here are the results:

- SQL Server: 17.04 sec
- MS Access: 3.92 sec

Based on what I read on page https://www.diericx.net/post/benchmark-embedded-dotnet-databases/ (in particular in this graph: https://www.diericx.net/images/embeddeddb4.png), I have very different results. By looking this graph, it seems that SQL Server should be at least **2.5 times faster** than MS Access.

I tried changing the connection string, no success so far. I ran the benchmarch on both Windows 10 Pro and on a Windows 2016 server, with similar results.

How could I increase the performance of SQL Server Express?
Thank you

---

***Edit**: this is the code I used for benchmarking (vbscript - ASP classic):*

```
<%
server.scripttimeout=9000000

gotest(1) ' MSSQL
gotest(0) ' MSACCESS

function gotest(DbMSSQL)
    response.write "DATABASE TYPE: <b>"
    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
    conn.CursorLocation=3 ' adUseClient
    
    select case DbMSSQL
        case "0": response.write "MSAccess"
                  PathDB="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\accessdb\accessdb.mdb"
                  Conn.Open ("PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE="&PathDB&"")
        case "1": response.write "MSSQL"
                  PathDB="sqldb"
                  conn.open("Provider=MSOLEDBSQL19;DataTypeCompatibility=80;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog="&pathdb&";User ID=sa;Password=Pnzip1xt-;Use Encryption for Data=False;Persist Security Info=True;TrustServerCertificate=True")              
                  
                  set RS=Conn.Execute("SELECT net_transport FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@SPID;")
                  if not RS.eof then response.write "</b><br>Connection type: <b>"&RS("net_transport")&"<br>"
                  
    end select

    response.write "</B><br>ADO Version: <b>"&Conn.Version&"</b><br><br>PERFORMANCE TEST IN PROGRESS...<br>"
    response.flush
    t1=timer
    randomize timer
    for dummy=1 to 2000
        iduten=(Int((53700-13123)*Rnd+13122))
        
        set RS=conn.execute("SELECT value FROM [fad] WHERE userid="&iduten&" AND module=1 AND course=1")
    
        if dummy=1 then
            response.write "<br>Cursor type: "&RS.cursortype
            response.write "<br>Cursor location: "&RS.cursorlocation
            response.write "<br>Cursor lock type: "&RS.LockType&"<br><br>"
        end if  
        if dummy mod 200=0 then
            response.write "X"
            response.flush
        end if
        if dummy mod 1000=0 then
            response.write " "&dummy&"<br>"
            response.flush
        end if
        RS.close
        set RS=nothing
        if not response.isclientconnected then response.end
    next    
    response.write "<br><br>TEST HAS ENDED. TIME TAKEN (sec): "
    response.write timer-t1
    response.write "<br><br>"
    Conn.close
    set conn=nothing
end function
%>
```

Comment: The index is called `ID`. Is it over a field called `ID`?

Comment: Try creating an index in both databases over the fields you are using in your `SELECT` statement, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Tryr this creating this index:: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_fad_userid_module_course ON dbo.fad(userid, module, course) INCLUDE(value);`. If the key values are unique, specify `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Thank you all for your advices! I added indexes on columns that are in the query and the result with SQL Server is now 5,62 sec, a nice improvement! (even if not as good as it should be if we look at the graph I mentioned)

Comment: Please show code for a [mre] so we can see how you are running ADO and measure timing.

Comment: do you need DataTypeCompatibility=80; ? Anyway, i hope you're not thinking about developing something new in Access

Comment: I added the code used for measure timing

Comment: Consider using parameters instead of string concatenation for the query, although I would not expect a significant performance difference here.

Comment: `After running this query for 2,000 times,` the results are meaningless.  Database servers cache data aggressively so repeating a query 2000 times won't take 2000 times more. You *are* paying for the cross-process call 2000 times though

Comment: Even worse, you're comparing accessing a file based database running *inside your application*, stored on your local drive with a database server running on a remote process.

Comment: If you want performance, don't do INLINE SQL ... do a Stored Procedure and CALL it instead.  And any line that is a response.write that you can combine will help .. condense the code ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access in general, and it been WIDE knowledge for the last 20+ years?

If you are pulling data on the SAME machine as the data? Access easy runs 2x or mote times faster then a server based system.

I don't think there should be ANY surprise here.

For one, the Access JET (now called ACE) data engine can and does directly read the file, and "scraps" the data right off the disk.

With SQL server?
You STILL going though a network layer, so you have tc/ip (network connection). You have a transaction based data engine, you have a separate software process and service, and a server based process in which the software has to "talk" to, and this is NOT a in-line software execution of code like you have with ms-access.

So, you have a Mount Everest of additional software layers between your software and the data file. You STILL using a socket type of connection to SQL server.

Quite much ZERO surprise that a direct disk file based system like Access will run circles around such a setup, and it always been that way.

However, having stated the above?

The INSTANT you start to have multiple users, then that is the instant that you ALREADY now will have a network connection involved. And that then tends to shift performance in favor of the server based system.

And using a server based system means that disk reads of data DOES NOT occur OVER the network.

And that means you can "send" the work to the server, let it beat up the disk drive (local on server), and THEN send the results.

With a file based system (like Access), then you have ZERO means to "send" the commands to the other end, since htere is NOT some other end. All processing occures client side. It just that in this example, both data and "process" are on the same server!

However, the instant that you go beyond the 1 user, that is ALSO the same instant that you now have a network involved, and that then is the very instant that a server based database system will start to show advantages.

As a typlical "genreal" statement?

if you migrate a access database to sql server, in MOST cases, you see a slow down if no network connection is between you and the data.

However, the instant that a network is placed between you and the database, then hands down, SQL server CAN run faster (note the word "can"!!! - it is not a automatic given that JUST adopting SQL server will make the Access front end application run faster).

In fact, Stackoverflow has been FILLED for the last 20+ years of posts of people who migrated their Access data to SQL server, and found things now run slower. So, this effect is NOT ANY kind of surprise here.

However, even one on one - say local computer?

You can still often find that SQL server will run faster then ACE/JET based queries - and this often is the result of the SQL server being able to "figure out" a better query plan then what JET/ACE will cook up. So, SQL server has received significant more R&D dollars over the years, and thus if you thow at SQL server some VERY bad formed quires, or some VERY poor SQL? SQL server will OFTEN still find a MUCH better way to execute that SQL due to a FAR better and more intelligent query plan builder.

So, for a simple table - raw data read?

No surprise, file based systems, be it reading a text file, or using access to scrape data from the disk drive? Such file systems are faster at raw read speeds, since there is FAR LESS systems and layers of software  between your code and the hard drive with data.

A great example?

Take your test code, and re-write the code as a stored procedure, and then run it 2000 times. it will run as fast (actually probably faster) then the ACE/jet sql, since we now removing the network bottle neck of transfer of data to the client.